# confusion on determining integral limits in bivarite distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bivariate-distributions

> $f(x_1,x_2)= 8x_1x_2 , 0<x_1<x_2<1 $ $\text{and}$ $0 , \text{elsewhere}$
>
> I want to find $E(X_1X_2^2).$

According to the book: $$E(X_1X_2^2) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x_2} (x_1x_2^28x_1x_2)dx_1dx_2$$

My question is about the border of $x_2$. Accoding to book , integral limits of $x_2$ is $(0,1)$ ,but i think that it is wrong ,because the inequalities are strict.For example , if $x_1 =0.13$ , then how can we assume that $x_2$ can be any value less than $0.13$ ,so i think that the limits should have been $(x_1,1)$ .Hence ,the correct one must be : $$E(X_1X_2^2) = \int_{x_1}^{1}\int_{0}^{x_2} (x_1x_2^28x_1x_2)dx_1dx_2$$

Am i correct ? If not ,can you please explain clearly , i am a beginner in this topic. Thanks in advance

Comment: The condition $x_1<x_2$ is already taken into account in the second integral, since you integrate with respect to $x_1$ on the interval $(0,x_2)$. So no need to add it again.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let's describe the domain, what are the values that $x_2$ can take? It takes value between $0$ and $1$.

Now, let's describe the values that $x_1$ can take in terms of $x_2$. We have $0 < x_1<x_2$.

In summary, we want to have $0<x_2 < 1$ and $0<x_1 < x_2$.

Comment: View it as you determines $x_2$ first, then after that you decide $x_1$. The inner integral can describe the bounds using variables that have been used in outer integral, not the other way round.  If you do programming, take it as an outside for loop and inner for loop.