# Confusing in limits of bivarite distribution and contradiction in related question

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, bivariate-distributions

This question is from "Mathematical Statistics with application by Wackerly and Mendelhall" $8th$ edition page $233$ ,question $5.5$ :

> $f(y_1,y_2)=3y_1 , 0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq1$ and $0$ , elsewhere.
>
> Find $F(1/2 ,1/3) =P(Y_1 \leq 1/2,Y_2 \leq 1/3)$.

I am beginner in statistics , so there are something i could not understand.I tried to solve this question ,but my answer and answer key is different.First of all , i want you to check my solution to see what i am missing.

$\mathbf{\text{MY ATTEMPT:}}$

$$\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1/3}3y_1dy_2dy_1 =\int_{0}^{1/2}\bigg(\int_{0}^{1/3}3y_1dy_2\bigg)dy_1$$

$$\bigg(\int_{0}^{1/3}3y_1dy_2\bigg) =3y_1\times(1/3) - 3y_1\times (0)=y_1$$

$$\int_{0}^{1/2}y_1dy_1 =\frac{y_1^2}{2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{8} - 0=0.125$$

However , the answer key says that answer is $0.1065$

What am i missing.

I want to add something such that when we solve continuous bivarite probablities , is $ 0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq1$ equal to $0 <y_2 < y_1 <1$  or $0 <y_2 \leq y_1 <1$ or $0 \leq y_2 < y_1 <1$ or $0 <y_2 < y_1 \leq1$ .I always confuse when i see $\leq$ and $<$ ,somebooks use $<$ , but somebooks use $\leq$.Can you also explain how to approach these signs in bivarite probability. Thanks in advance..

By the way , do not forget that i am a beginner , so please explain like explaining to an dummy..

Answer (score 1):

The rule of $3y_1$ only holds when $0 \le y_2 \le y_1 \le 1$, it takes zero otherwise.

[image]

Let's describe the region, what are the values that $y_2$ can take? It takes value between $0$ and $\frac13$.

What are the values that $y_1$ can take in term of $y_2$, it takes value between $y_2$ and $\frac12$.

The limit of the integral should be

\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac13 \int_{y_2}^\frac12 3y_1 \,\, dy_1 dy_2 &= \int_0^\frac13 \frac32y_1^2|_{y_2}^\frac12 \, dy_2 \\
&= \frac32\int_0^\frac13 \frac14 - y_2^2 \, dy_2\\
&= \frac32 \left(\frac1{12} - \frac1{81} \right)\\
&=\frac12 \left(\frac14 -\frac1{27}\right)
\end{align}

For continuous variable, the random variable takes a particular value with probability $0$, hence the equality does not matter.

Comment: First of all thanks , but i have many question in my head. Firstly , why " the rule of $3y_1$ holds only when $0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq 1$ and why not $0 <y_2 <y_1 <1$ ? What is the importance ,i.e difference ,of $\leq$ and $<$ in bivarite distribution ? Secondly , you used $y_2$ as the lower limit of $y_1$ , but there is $\leq$ sign , so is it not mean that $y_1$ can be equal to zero ? How can you restrict $y_1$ with $y_2$ when there are $\leq$ signs ?

Comment: I found this similar question : *[LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341993/confusion-on-determining-integral-limits-in-bivarite-distribution)* , According to your logic , i think the integral of this quesion must have been $$\int_{x_1}^{1}\int_{0}^{x_2}$$ .Am i right ?

Comment: This is from your question $(_1,_2)=3_1,0\le _2\le y_1\le 1$. Note that it has to integrat to $1$ to be a density function, it can't  be any function. The difference between $\le$ and $<$ it not specific to bivariate distribution. For **continuous**variable, the probability that it takes a particular value is $0$, that is $P(X \le a)  = P(X < a)$.  Probability of zero does not mean it doesn't occur, it means it takes measure $0$. To write down the integral, try to draw out the region and describe it.

Comment: no, the limit of the integral is not correct, in particular, if we want the final answer to be a number, we can't have a variable as a boundary for the outer most integral.

Comment: for the question in the given link  : but it does not make sense , i agree with you interpretion that "For continuousvariable, the probability that it takes a particular value is 0" , so if  $x_1 <x_2$ , how can we say that limit of $x_2$ is from zero to one. what if  for example $x_1 =0.022$ and $x_2 =0.020$ , if we say that the limit of $x_2$ is from zero to one and it take $0.020$ and the limit of $x_1$ is from $0$ to $x_2$ and it takes $0.022$ ,does this values  not distrupt the inequality of $x_1 <x_2$ ?

Comment: briefly i  say that in any condition ,the lowest limit of $x_2$ must be $x_1$  because $x_1 <x_2$

Comment: If you impose $0<x_2 < 1$ and  $0<x_1 < x_2$, it is implied that $x_1 < x_2$.

Comment: I think my problem is not about probability , it is about taking double integral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132764/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-young-mathematician).